# How to divide a series of values in one array by a series of values in another array

Tags: java, arrays, division

I am a beginner in Java and would like to ask some help with a array problem I am having. I am trying to build a simple program that has two int type arrays with 5 integers in each array. I want to divide the length of integers in one array by the length of integers in the other array. My program seems to work to some extent, since it gives me the results of the divisions. However it also gives me the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at ArrayDivide.main(ArrayDivide.java:11)

Can someone tell me once going wrong? Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayDivide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr1[]={8,4,6,8,4};
        int arr2[]={2,4,2,1,2};

        for (int x =0;x <arr1.length;x++){
            for (int j =0;x <arr2.length;j++){
                int result = arr1[x] / arr2[j]; 

                System.out.println(result);

            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Divide each number of outer array (arr1) with respective number in other array(arr2)**

The code is shown below. You should also put check to verify that both arrays have same length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[]={8,4,6,8,4};
        int arr2[]={2,4,2,1,2};

        for (int x =0;x <arr1.length;x++){
                int result = arr1[x] / arr2[x];
                System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
4
1
3
8
2
```

**Divide each number of outer array(arr1) with each number in other array (arr2)**

And if you want to divide each number of outer array with each number of inner array then use the below code. In your code condition is not right, it should be `j <arr2.length` and not `x <arr2.length`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[]={8,4,6,8,4};
        int arr2[]={2,4,2,1,2};

        for (int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
            for (int j =0;j<arr2.length;j++){
                int result = arr1[i] / arr2[j];

                System.out.println(result);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that solved it. Thank you very much. I'll mark your response as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change second loop to

```
 for (int j =0;j <arr2.length;j++){
```

ie `j <arr2.length` from `x <arr2.length`

Loop

> **for (initialization; condition ;updation)**

Since you dint compare `j` in `condition` part loop moves on giving you exception at the `5th` index

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayDivide {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr1[]={8,4,6,8,4};
    int arr2[]={2,4,2,1,2};

    for (int x =0;x <arr1.length;x++){
            int result = arr1[x] / arr2[x]; 

            System.out.println(result);
     }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` exceptions occurs when you try to access an item who's index is greater than the array's size.

Here in the above code :

```
       for (int x =0 ; x < arr1.length ; x++){
            for (int j =0 ; 0 < arr2.length ; j++){
                int result = arr1[x] / arr2[j]; 

                System.out.println(result);

            }
        }
```

You have ***x < arr2.lengh***.

Suppose your arr1 length is 10 and arr2 length is 5, in this case when j ll be 6, it ll still be less than 10 and your code int `result = arr1[x] / arr2[j];` ll try to access arr2[6] which ll produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

To fix this, in the inner loop you need to check from 0 to arr2's length.

**Answer :**

```
           for (int x =0;x <arr1.length;x++){
                for (int j =0;x <arr2.length;j++){
                    int result = arr1[x] / arr2[j]; 

                    System.out.println(result);

                }
            }
```